# Secret code decoder not working properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have wrote a simple "secret code" program that translates letters of the alphabet to a series of numbers. The encoder program I wrote works, but the decoder doesnt. Here is the code for the decoder:

```
print("decode")
message = input("input: ")  
encoded = ""

for char in message:
    if char == "7777":
        encoded += "a"
    elif char == "7778":
        encoded += "b"
    elif char == "7788":
        encoded += "c"
    elif char == "7888":
        encoded += "d"
    elif char == "8887":
        encoded += "e"
    ...
    elif char == "4554":
        encoded += "y"
    elif char == "4444":
        encoded += "z"
    else:
        encoded += char

print("+-----------------------------+")
print("output: ")
print(encoded)
print("+-----------------------------+")
```

The output is just the number, for example when I input "7777" it outputs "7777" when its supposed to output "a". Any help appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You are iterating over the characters. They will be of length 1 and will never compare equal to a 4 character string. It's not clear what you are trying to do. You may need to take the string in 4 character chunks and do the comparison or even convert to int and compare that.

Comment: @PaulRooney what do you mean?

Comment: may I also suggest holding the char and it's translation in a dictionary? would help to eliminate all these conditionals

Comment: About which part? If you enter `'7777'`, The result of your for loop is a series of `'7'`s, none of which compare equal to any of your conditions. `'7'` is not equal to `'7777'`. Try printing `char` at the top of the loop to see what I mean.

Comment: @eagle how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is quite simple. Since you are looping over the array, you are checking *each individual character*, when you want to check every *four* characters (Which evaluate to a letter). Change your loop to:

```
for i in range(0, len(message), 4):
```

This loop now iterates over every four indices in the string, which you can then use to create a new string that represents the current word:

```
currentWord = message[i:i+3]
```

Now you should check this new variable in all of your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `for` statement:

```
for char in message:
```

This iterates through the individual characters of the message.  Your decoding, however, requires that you take 4-character slices of the input string.  Instead, try something like

```
for i in range(0, len(message), 4):
    char = message[i:i+3]
    ...
```

Beyond that, there are many improvements to make int the code -- most especially, a translation table of some sort  @eagle already suggested the most common, a dictionary.